# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.isAnonymous()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, nullpointerexception, anonymous

Hi Please help me to resolve this issue  I m getting this error
message. The app crashes I have tried almost every solution suggested
on Google

I am creating a Notes application for Android and the logic of the app when it starts is to check if there is a user created and logged in or not. if there is a user created then start MainActivity
if there is no user created login with Anonymous account

```
 package com.russrezepov.mynotes;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
 import com.russrezepov.mynotes.auth.Login;

 public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth fAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                //create a new Anonymous account if a User is not logged in or does not have an account
                fAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(Splash.this, "Logged in with Temp Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Splash.this, "Error" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

}

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.russrezepov.mynotes, PID: 5158
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.russrezepov.mynotes/com.russrezepov.mynotes.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.isAnonymous()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.isAnonymous()' on a null object reference
        at com.russrezepov.mynotes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5158 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:54989', transport: 'socket'
```

The Error message shows that `if (user.isAnonymous())` is where the code below is  stops

```
package com.russrezepov.mynotes;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.russrezepov.mynotes.auth.Login;
import com.russrezepov.mynotes.auth.Register;
import com.russrezepov.mynotes.model.Note;
import com.russrezepov.mynotes.note.AddNote;
import com.russrezepov.mynotes.note.EditNote;
import com.russrezepov.mynotes.note.TheNoteDetails;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    NavigationView nav_view;
    RecyclerView noteList;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    private FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    //private Adapter adapter;
    //private NoteAdapter noteAdapter;
    final static String TAG = "Firebase Not Reading";
    final static String TAGF = "Firebase CONNECTED";


    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note,NoteViewHolder> noteAdapter;

    //>>>ON CREATE <<<
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Log.i(TAGF,"onCreate");

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();
        noteList = findViewById(R.id.noteList);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.addNoteFloat);


        View headerView = nav_view.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView userDisplayName = headerView.findViewById(R.id.userDisplayName);
        TextView userDisplayEmail = headerView.findViewById(R.id.userDisplayEmail);

        if (user.isAnonymous()) {
            userDisplayName.setText("Temporary Account");
            userDisplayEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            userDisplayEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
            userDisplayName.setText(user.getDisplayName());

        }

        setUpRecyclerView();


        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), AddNote.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_down);
                finish();

            }

        });

    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {

        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
        //query notes=>UID=>MyNotes=>user all notes
        Query query = fStore.collection("notes").document(user.getUid()).collection("myNotes").orderBy("title",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        //executing the query
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> allNotes;
        allNotes = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
                .setQuery(query, Note.class)
                .build();

//        fStore.collection("notes")
//                .get()
//                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
//                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
//                            Log.i(TAGF,"Firebase Connected Successfully");
//                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
//                                //titles.add(document.getString("title"));
//                                //content.add(document.getString("content"));
//                                Log.i(TAGF,document.getString("title"));
//                                Log.i(TAGF,document.getString("content"));
//                                Log.i(TAGF,"Firebase Connected Successfully");
//                            }
//                        } else {
//                            Log.w(TAG,"Error getting documents.", task.getException());
//                        }
//                    }
//                });

        noteAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteViewHolder> (allNotes) {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder noteViewHolder, final int i, @NonNull final Note note) {

                //Binding data from MainActivity, when Adapter object is created, to this View that we have here
                noteViewHolder.noteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
                noteViewHolder.noteContent.setText(note.getContent());
                final int colorCodes = getRandomColor();
                noteViewHolder.mCardView.setBackgroundColor(noteViewHolder.view.getResources().getColor(colorCodes,null));
                //getting each doc id to be able to update them in EditNote using i as a position in collections
                final String docId = noteAdapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(i).getId();

                noteViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //getting current context where we are starting the Activity and passing them to another activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), TheNoteDetails.class);

                        //When someone clicks on the first item in the RecyclerView it is going to get the position as Zero -> Position
                        //passing the title and description to the NoteDetails
                        i.putExtra("title", note.getTitle());
                        i.putExtra("content", note.getContent());
                        i.putExtra("color", colorCodes);
                        i.putExtra("noteId",docId);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(i); //Not passing anything yet. Just getting current context and passing current context

                    }
                });

                //Adding menu Edit & Delete functionality for each Note in Main Activity
                ImageView menuIcon = noteViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.menuIcon);
                menuIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                        final String docId = noteAdapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(i).getId();
                        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(),v);
                        popupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                        popupMenu.getMenu().add("Edit").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditNote.class);
                                i.putExtra("title",note.getTitle());
                                i.putExtra("content",note.getContent());
                                i.putExtra("noteId",docId);
                                startActivity(i);
                                return false;

                            }
                        });
                       popupMenu.getMenu().add("Delete").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                               DocumentReference docRef = fStore.collection("notes").document(user.getUid()).collection("myNotes").document(docId);
                               docRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   }
                               }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Deleting Note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   }
                               });

                               return false;
                           }
                       });

                       popupMenu.show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_view_layout,parent, false);
                return new NoteViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        //Staggered layout expands based on Context Size
        noteList.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        noteList.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addNote:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AddNote.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_down);
                break;

            case R.id.sync:
                // sending Anonymous users only to Sync Activity aka Register New Account
                if (user.isAnonymous()) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_down);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You Are Already Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.logout:
               checkUser();
                break;


            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Coming Soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void checkUser() {
        //Check if the user is real or Anonymous
        if (user.isAnonymous()) {
            displayAlert();
        } else {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splash.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_down);
        }
    }

    private void displayAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder warnignAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                .setMessage("you are logged in with Temp account. Logging out will delete all unsaved notes")
                .setPositiveButton("Sync Note", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Logout", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //TODO: delete all the notes created by the anonymous user
//                        fStore.collection("notes").document(user.getUid()).document()
//                        fStore.collection("notes").document(user.getUid())
//                                .delete()
//                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
//                                    @Override
//                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
//                                        Log.d(TAG, "Notes successfully deleted!");
//                                    }
//                                })
//                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
//                                    @Override
//                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
//                                        Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting Notes", e);
//                                    }
//                                });

                        //TODO: delete the anonymous user
                        user.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Splash.class));
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_down);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        warnignAlert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Menu is Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        noteAdapter.startListening();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
            noteAdapter.stopListening();

    }

    public static class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView noteTitle, noteContent;
        View view;
        CardView mCardView;

        private NoteViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            noteTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titles);
            noteContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
            mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.noteCard);
            view = itemView; //Handles clicks on Recycle View items. Clicks are redirected to the inside of a Note
        }
    }

    private int getRandomColor() {
        List<Integer> colorCode = new ArrayList<>();
        colorCode.add(R.color.blue);
        colorCode.add(R.color.yellow);
        colorCode.add(R.color.skyBlue);
        colorCode.add(R.color.lightPurple);
        colorCode.add(R.color.lightGreen);
        colorCode.add(R.color.greenlight);
        colorCode.add(R.color.gray);
        colorCode.add(R.color.pink);
        colorCode.add(R.color.red);
        colorCode.add(R.color.notgreen);

        Random randomColor = new Random();
        int numberColor = randomColor.nextInt(colorCode.size());
        return colorCode.get(numberColor);
    }


}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **500** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the user object after accessing it. You are doing it in `setUpRecyclerView` but accessing it before.

```
    setUpRecyclerView();
    if (user.isAnonymous()) {
                userDisplayName.setText("Temporary Account");
                userDisplayEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
                userDisplayEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
                userDisplayName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
    }
```

This will make sure you have user object before using it.